# How to write a SQLAlchemy event listener for when a view within a specific Postgres schema is dropped?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

In my app, whenever a view within a certain Postgres schema is dropped, I want to call a specific function. I am familiar with SQLAlchemy's `event.listener` functionality, but I have mainly seen it used to listen for table inserts, updates, and deletes. I have looked over the documentation [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html), but there doesn't appear to be anything related to dropping views, or views in general (yes, I understand that what I'm trying to do is somewhat unique).  Is there a way for me to listen to `DROP VIEW specific_schema_name.my_table` queries executed from SQLAlchemy, where I want to catch it if it matches `specific_schema_name`?

I understand that SQLAlchemy doesn't have much, if any, built-in support for drop statements or views. How would one go about creating such a listener?

Comment: You seem to want something like a trigger that fires on drop view DDL, but within SQLAlchemy and for drops dispatched within SQLAlchemy, right?

Comment: @CraigRinger Correct. I need to run a particular function within my Python app whenever a view is dropped. I don't expect to have views dropped outside of the Python app, but if so it would be nice to catch them, but not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

you would most likely just listen for executions, and look at the string value for what you need:

```
from sqlalchemy import event
import re

@event.listens_for(my_engine, "after_cursor_execute")
def my_thing(conn, cursor, statement, parameters, context, executemany):
    if re.match(r'DROP VIEW my_table', statement):
        call_my_function()
```